# compare lines within a single file using python

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I have a text file that has space delimited data as follows:

```
aaa bbb 10
aaa bbb 5
aaa bbb 6
aaa bbb 2
aaa ccc 4
aaa ccc 11
aaa ccc 7
aaa ddd 9
aaa ddd 13
aaa ddd 12
aaa ddd 19
xxx yyy 20
xxx yyy 4
xxx yyy 6
xxx yyy 8
xxx yyy 12
xxx zzz 10
xxx zzz 11
xxx zzz 4
xxx zzz 5
xxx zzz 6
```

I'm not sure how to explain this in words but I want to write the lines with the biggest numerical value to a separate file.

The output should look like:

```
aaa bbb 10
aaa ccc 11
aaa ddd 19
xxx yyy 20
xxx zzz 11
```

Here is some code I've tried, but hasn't worked

```
for line in r.readlines()[1:]:
    z = re.split(' ', line)
    a = []
    a.append(z)
    for i in xrange(len(a)):
        if z[0] == a[i][0] and z[1] == a[i][1]:
            if z[7] > a[i][7]:
               del a[i]
               a.append(z)
    for x in a:
    p.write(' '.join(x))
```

I didn't make this clear originally in the question (I'm trying not to give out too much information about the data I'm working with), but there are 8 "columns", in this file. The first three are alpha-numeric, the fourth is an integer, and the last four are floats. I need to use the very last column (a float) to be the maximum. Sorry about this!

Another Solution

```
allLines = r.readlines()

bestOf = re.split(' ', allLines[1])

f = open("results_filtered.txt", 'a')
for line in allLines[2:]:
   z = re.split(' ', line)
   if z[0] == bestOf[0] and z[1] == bestOf[1]:
       # match, compare signals
       if z[7] > bestOf[7]:
           bestOf = z
   else:
        # no match, next set
    f.write(' '.join(bestOf))
    bestOf = z
```

Comment: Are the lines sorted?

Comment: create a dictionary and compare and add the highest value to the value essentially?

Comment: @Martihn Pieters: the lines are not sorted

Comment: @crownedzero I guess I need to look up how dictionaries work. I was wondering if there was another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution assumes that the lines to compare are grouped together

```
allLines = r.readlines()
bestOf = re.split(' ', allLines)
f = open("output.txt", 'w')
for line in allLines[2:]:
    z = re.split(' ', line)
    if z[0] == bestOf[0] and z[1] == bestOf[1]:
        # match, compare values
        if z[7] > bestOf[7]:
            bestOf = z
    else:
        # no match, next set
        f.write(bestOf)
        bestOf = z
```

Similar to selection sort algorithm, if the line is better than the current best, take the line instead.  When the first two elements do not match, assume we have moved to another group and write the previous best to file.

Answer (score 2):

If the lines are not sorted, track the maxima using a dictionary or [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to track the maximum values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

maxima = defaultdict(int)

with open(inputfilename, 'r') as ifh:
    for line in ifh:
        key, value = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        value = int(value)
        if value > maxima[key]:
            maxima[key] = value

with open(outputfilename, 'w') as ofh:
    for key in sorted(maxima):
        ofh.write('{} {}\n'.format(key, maxima[key])
```

A regular dictionary would work too; you'd use `maxima = {}` and `if value > maxima.get(key, 0):` instead.

In the above sample code I use [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to split on the last whitespace in the line that separates two words; this ensures that we grab *just* the integer value at the end of the line. The rest of the line is used as the key.

If the 'key' is only taken from *part* of the line, then split out the line further, and store both the maximum and the line. If the values are really floats, you may want to start out with `float('-inf')` as the 'maximum' for that key so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict

maxima = defaultdict(lambda: (float('-inf'), ''))

with open(inputfilename, 'r') as ifh:
    for line in ifh:
        columns = line.rsplit(None, 1)
        key = tuple(columns[:2])    # first two columns are the key
        value = float(columns[-1])  # last column is the value
        if value > maxima[key][0]:
            maxima[key] = (value, line)

with open(outputfilename, 'w') as ofh:
    for key in sorted(maxima):
        # write the tracked lines
        ofh.write(maxima[key][1])
```

Now both the maximum value *and* the whole line with that maximum are stored, per key. What you pick for a key is up to you; I picked the first two columns.

Comment: I didn't make this clear in the question (I'm trying not to give out too much information about the data I'm working with), but there are 8 "columns", in this file. The first three are alpha-numeric, the fourth is an integer, and the last four are floats. I need to use the very last column (a float) to be the maximum. Sorry about this!

Comment: @user2977350: Then use `float(value)` instead; the rest would not change. You can use `defaultdict(lambda: float('-inf'))` if there are negative float values in the file.

Comment: @user2977350: Is your file in CSV format using tab separators, by any chance?

Comment: edit: TypeError: 'file' object is not subscriptable when I try for line in ifh[1:]:

Comment: The only problem I'm encountering is that the first line in the input file is a header (that lists the names of the columns). I'm trying to use [1:] like I did in other parts of my code for it to skip the first line, but it's not working.

Comment: @user2977350: ah, no, the file object is an *iterable*. You can do `header = next(ofh)` to store it in a variable before looping, then write the header to the other file.

Comment: @user2977350: I am using the file in a memory efficient manner, by asking for the next line only when needed. Nowhere is the whole file read into memory in one go.

Comment: Where exactly would I put that? Also, if I just remove the header from the input file, I get this error   

File "CPSM_wrapper.py", line 58, in <module>
    if value > maxima[key][0]:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Right after the `with open(...) as ifh:` line.

Comment: Sorry, the key can indeed not be a list, fixed that.

Comment: If I put header = next(ofh) right after the with open(...) as ifh, wouldn't I get a NameError?. I never use ofh before in the code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `next(ifh)` (input file handle).

Comment: Interestingly, when I used the code I got the carbon copy of the input file. It's the same problem I was having with other methods. Am I over complicating this haha?

Comment: @user2977350: Then your keys are all unique. Without a better example this is as far as I can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to group likes and then use `max` with a key value on the last column converted to a float:

```
data='''\
aaa bbb 10 2.2
aaa bbb 5 3.3
aaa bbb 6 55
aaa bbb 2 6.66
aaa ccc 4 22
aaa ccc 11 35.5
aaa ccc 7 66
aaa ddd 9 .00001
aaa ddd 13 1e10
aaa ddd 12 1e-22
aaa ddd 19 22
xxx yyy 20 123456
xxx yyy 4 66.6666
xxx yyy 6 26
xxx yyy 8 35
xxx yyy 12 2e99
xxx zzz 10 45
xxx zzz 11 55
xxx zzz 4 65
xxx zzz 5 1
xxx zzz 6 12345'''

d={}

for line in data.splitlines():
    l=line.split()
    k=' '.join(l[0:2])      # select how many columns comprise a group
    d.setdefault(k,[]).append(line)

for k in sorted(d):
    max(d[k], key=lambda s: float(s.rsplit(' ',1)[1]))
```

Prints:

```
aaa bbb 6 55
aaa ccc 7 66
aaa ddd 13 1e10
xxx yyy 12 2e99
xxx zzz 6 12345
```

Comment: I didn't make this clear in the question (I'm trying not to give out too much information about the data I'm working with), but there are 8 "columns", in this file. The first three are alpha-numeric, the fourth is an integer, and the last four are floats. I need to use the very last column (a float) to be the maximum. Sorry about this!

Comment: @user2977350: How are you grouping the groups for the max of the group? i.e., same 2 columns make a group or first 3 columns?

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you need that the three left most columns are your identifiers, this should work:

```
f = open("test.txt", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

identifiers = set([' '.join(line.split()[0:2]) for line in lines])
output = []

for identifier in identifiers:
    output.append((' '.join(line.split()[:-1], max([float(line.split()[-1]) for line in lines if ' '.join(line.split()[0:2]) == identifier])))

f = open("newFile.txt", 'w')
for item in output:
    f.write("{} {}\n".format(item[0],item[1]))
f.close()
```

Comment: This almost worked! I just need to copy all the columns for the selected output rows.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, but I also have another solution!

Comment: I still gave you credit as best as I could with marking you as having the solution. I'm not entirely sure how SO works in gaining reputation and the like, but I hope this works!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) is the SO help page on reputation, if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

If you have numerous fields, it's worth using pandas (here `data` is your sample as text):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep=' ',header=None)
```

duplicate second column for test purpose

```
>>> df[3]=df[2]
```

group by needed columns (first two for this example)

```
>>> gb = df.groupby([0,1])
```

and compute max

```
>>> gb.max().reset_index()
     0    1   2   3
0  aaa  bbb  10  10
1  aaa  ccc  11  11
2  aaa  ddd  19  19
3  xxx  yyy  20  20
4  xxx  zzz  11  11
```

Comment: I didn't make this clear in the question (I'm trying not to give out too much information about the data I'm working with), but there are 8 "columns", in this file. The first three are alpha-numeric, the fourth is an integer, and the last four are floats. I need to use the very last column (a float) to be the maximum. Sorry about this!

Answer (score 0):

Does the following shell command do what you want?

```
sort -nk3 $filename | tail
```

This is for the demo data above, and gives:

```
aaa ccc 11
xxx zzz 11
aaa ddd 12
xxx yyy 12
aaa ddd 13
aaa ddd 19
xxx yyy 20
```

(replacing `$filename` with the file name, of course...)

For the 8 column version you mention, simply replace the `k3` with `k8`, or whichever column numbers you need...

Comment: probably correct (haven't verified tho) but the question was about Python :)

Comment: Yes, I know... but I figured that for reference, someone else may find this question when they don't care about which language, and so it'd good reference.  Also, sometimes it's easier to "shell out" with `subprocess.check_output("sort -nk3 '{}'|tail".format(fn), shell=true)` than it is to do things 'properly'.  If its a one off script, then why not? ;-)

Comment: ...because for example it ties the one off script to Unix platforms?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use any external libraries or any max functions. The simplest way to do this is to use the first two items as an index into a dictionary and update the item in that dictionary if it's larger than the existing item while you're reading the data in.

```
output_dict = {}
with open(input_file, 'r') as input:
    for row in input:
        id, value = row.rsplit(' ', 1)
        value = int(value)
        if id not in output_dict or value > output_dict[id]:
            output_dict[id] = value


with open(output_file, 'w') as output:
    for id in output_dict:
        output.write('{0} {1}\n'.format(id, output_dict[id]))
```

Replace 'input_file' and 'output_file' with file paths and this will work as is, and it should be relatively easy to understand. For your data containing floats, you can replace 'int' with 'float' and it should still work.